# Inventory program only reads one line?

Tags: java, bufferedreader, filereader, inventory

So I've been having trouble with this program for a long time now. The assignment wants me to read a .txt file using `BufferedReader`, `FileReader` and `StringTokenizer`, create an array, then print all the information. I went to my professor for help and she hashed out a skeleton for me, but after some editing this is what I've come up with:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class Inventory {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        final int MAX = 500;
        InventoryItem[] items = new InventoryItem[MAX];
        StringTokenizer tokenizer;
        String line, name, file = "inventory.txt";
        int price, units, count = 0;

        try {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
            BufferedReader inFile = new BufferedReader(fr);
            line = inFile.readLine();

            while ((line = inFile.readLine()) != null) {
                tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);

                while (tokenizer.hasMoreElements()) {
                    name = tokenizer.nextToken();

                    try {
                        units = Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken());
                        price = Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken());
                        items[count++] = new InventoryItem(name, units, price);

                    } catch (NumberFormatException exception) {
                        System.out.println("Error in input. Line ignored:");
                        System.out.println(line);
                    }
                    line = inFile.readLine();
                }
            }

            inFile.close();
            for (int scan = 0; scan < count; scan++)
                System.out.println(items[scan]);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException exception) {
            System.out.println("The file " + file + " was not found.");
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            System.out.println(exception);
        }
        stdin.read();
    }
}
```

The program compiles with no issue, but when I run it it prints out the exception error line *"Error in input. Line ignored"*, then prints out the second line in my .txt file, then doesn't read the next line and stays in the run.

Even after this the assignment wants me to output the data in a certain way, which I don't know how to do without `System.out.println`.

Here is the InventoryItem code:

```
 import java.util.*;
 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.text.DecimalFormat;

 public class InventoryItem
{
   public static String name;
   private int units;
   private double price;

   /**
    * Default Constructor
    */
   public InventoryItem()
   {
   this (name, 3, 20.00);
   }
   /**
    * Non-Default Constructor
    * Constructs new InventoryItem class with parameters name, units
    * and price from main class. 
    * 
    * @param name   name of item
    * @param units  number of units
    * @param price  price of item
    */
   public InventoryItem (String name, int units, double price)
   {
   this.name = name;
   this.units = units;
   this.price = price;
   }
   /**
    * Returns the name
    * 
    * @return returns name of item
    */
   public String getName()
    {
   return name;
   }
   /**
    * Sets the name
    *
    * @param name The name of the unit
    */
   public void setName(String name)
   {
   this.name = name;
   }
   /**
    * Returns the number of units
    *
    * @return returns the number of units
    */
   public int getUnits()
   {
   return units;
   }
   /**
    * Sets the number of units
    *
    * @param units the number of units
    */
   public void setUnits(int units)
   {
   this.units = units;
   }
   /**
    * Returns the price of each unit
    *
    * @return returns the price
    */
    public double getPrice()
   {
   return price;
   }
   /**
    * Sets the price
    *
    * @param price the price of each unit
    */
   public void setPrice(double price)
   {
   this.price = price;
   }
   /**
    * Returns the data in the form of an array
    *
    * @param name the name of the unit
    * @param units the number of units
    * @param price the price of each unit
    * @return Returns the inputted data in a specified format
    */
    public String toString()
   {
   DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

   return name + ":\t" + units + "\t" + price + "\t" +
   fmt.format((units * price));
   }

}
```

Comment: Why are you reading the line twice in your while loop? Also can you print tokenizer.nextToken() instead of parsing it and then tell us the output?

Comment: Looks much like: https://community.oracle.com/thread/1204286

Comment: "the assignment wants me to output the data in a certain way, which I don't know how to do" - we don't either. There aren't any clear requirements here...

Comment: My professor wants the output to have the name of the item , the number of units, price, and total cost (units*price). However, as the code is now it does not read the first line of the .txt file, and only prints out the second line and gets stuck in the run without ending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have made two errors.

Prices contain decimals, so you can't use int. float is one possibility (although, in general, not recommended):

```
float price;
//...
      price = Float.parseFloat(tokenizer.nextToken());
```

The second error is reading each line twice. The following change avoids this:

```
   line = inFile.readLine();     
   while( line != null ) {
       //...
       line = inFile.readLine();
   }
```

Note that you can simplify this:

```
   while( (line = inFile.readLine()) != null {
       //...
   }
```

To print you items, write a suitable method `public String toString()` in your InventoryItem class.

**Later**

The code for InventoryItem must be fixed:

```
 public class InventoryItem {
     private String name = "";
     private int units;
     private double price;

     public InventoryItem(){
     }

     public InventoryItem (String name, int units, double price){
         this.name = name;
         this.units = units;
         this.price = price;
     }
     // ... etc
}
```

There is really no point in providing fancy values for an object created with the default constructor. Assigning the empty string `""` to `name` is reasonable to avoid NPE; int and double fields are best left at 0.

Alternatively, simply remove the default constructor.

Comment: I changed price to a double and changed my toString method in my InventoryItem class. However, I don't understand why my program is reading each line twice. The simplified version that you posted is already in my program. As of right now the program no longer prints out an error message, but still skips the first line, and reads and prints out the last two lines, with the incorrect names.

Comment: It might have something to do with stdin.read or the tokenizer.

Comment: No - it has something to do with an error in your code. Do you really have only **one** call of `inFile.readLine()` - as in the "simplified version"?

Comment: Ah I see what you're saying now. I got rid of one of the lines and it now reads all three lines, but now the tokenizer only reads one of the 'name' tokens, namely the last one. So the output should give me three lines each with a different name (Basketball, Baseball, then Soccerball), but it prints out Soccerball for all three lines, but prints the units and price correctly.

Comment: Do you want me to guess what you have in your class `InventoryItem`? Any `static`? If yes: what do you think it does?

Comment: There are no static methods in my InventoryItem class.

Comment: No static fields? Can you add the code of that class?

Comment: I've added the IventoryItem code, and I now realize that I declared name a static variable, but if I remove the static modifier, the code doesn't compile and tells me "Cannot reference name before supertype constructor has been called".

Comment: I told you there is static in your class. - See my extended answer. That's it!

Comment: Thanks very much. Sorry for being a pain, but I was given this program when I haven't been lectured on half the methods or material required.